# Richfaces specific datatable header orientation

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I need to implement data table with vertical header orientation and header that's take not whole row, through one cell(like in image fifth row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is to use `<rich:column styleClass="rich-table-subheadercell">`  or `tyleClass="rf-dt-shdr-c"` for 4.x